# Length of edges of an image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, edge-detection, canny-operator

I am trying to compute the average length of the edges of an image using python. I could compute the number of edges using opencv Canny detection as follows:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
edge_count = np.count_nonzero(edges)
```

I'm stuck on how to compute the length of edges.
In matlab, we could get an edge image using `edge()` function and then `sum(sum(edgeimage))` gives the length of the image as per my research.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can count the number of points in all contours

Answer (score -2):

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image('image.png')
(width, height) = im.size()
```

PIL is the Python Imaging Library. Normally use it when needing to do any sort of image analysis or screen captures.

Comment: I am looking for edge length.